# Is it possible to control a Motoman SV3 (MRCII controller) with ROS

Tags: ros, microcontroller, motoman

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have to work with this old industrial style robot for a university project. Does anyone have experience controlling this robot with ROS by any chance? Or have any other experience for controlling it? Or by any chance does someone have the Yasakawa mode password for the MRCIIs?

Thanks,
James

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41820/is-it-possible-to-control-a-motoman-sv3-(mrcii-controller)-with-ros/) by [robaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/3051/robaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should look at the ROS Industrial stack: http://ros.org/wiki/Industrial/supported_hardware
Currently only DX100 controllers are supported. For the password you should contact your Yasakawa representative.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2012-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0